# NoMethodError when implementing Instagram Gem for Ruby on Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram, instagram-api

I have just completed One Month Rails tutorial and this is the website I've build: https://warwicktri.herokuapp.com/. Now I'm trying to pull an Instagram feed onto the home page but I get the NoMethodError in Pins#index on my localhost.

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

<div>
  <% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
    <%= image_tag instagram.images.first.last.url %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I think that it means that @instagram is not declared properly but I do not know where did I go wrong.

This is the code in my pins_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  respond_with(@pins)
  @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")
  respond_with(@instagram)
end
```

I also tried putting @instagram in another controller by itself instead, but I still get the same error:

```
class InstagramController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")
    respond_with(@instagram)
  end
end
```

How should I declare @instagram in my code?

Update 1: My code for view (index.html.erb):

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p><%= pin.description %></p>
        <p><strong><%= pin.user.name if pin.user %></strong></p>
        <% if pin.user == current_user %>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= link_to edit_pin_path(pin) do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span> Edit
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span> Delete
            <% end %>
          </div>
        <% end %>  
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="center">
  <%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>

<div>
    <% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
      <%= image_tag instagram.images.first.last.url %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that you are rendering the view that isn't belong to the action, in your case that is `index`.

Comment: what is the view have you?

Comment: run `Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")` in rails console may be it is return `nil`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, I have updated the code for my view (index.html.erb). Do you mind explaining your first statement? Sorry, I just started Rails a month ago so I'm still very amateur in it.

Comment: @RajarshiDas, I've done that and I was returned a whole block of code which is related to the user's instagram account. I see the captions of the posts, username, filter information, etc.

Comment: @AlfredLua well, 2 questions, the problem, is appeared only on heroku, but on local host all is ok? and 2nd: is the `@pins` variable set on heroku?

Comment: Try getting rid of the respond_with parts. My guess is that respond_with(@pins) is causing your controller action to skip the rest of the part, though that doesn't explain why the InstagramController by itself doesn't work. Also when you run @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635") in the rails console to double check that it pulls something, make sure it responds to .each in there too.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, 1) I have not pushed it to Heroku yet. The problem is appears in local host so I didn't want to push to Heroku. 2) I think that's a yes. If you go to the link, you can see that the pins are working fine.

Comment: @mattangriffel, I got the same error after I removed the respond_with parts. Yeah and like you said, if that's the issue, InstagramController by itself should work. Both (add symbol)instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635") and .each give me data from the instagram account. I've pushed my files to my GitHub repo if it helps (https://github.com/alfredlua/pinteresting)

Comment: @AlfredLua well that is case for debug, add the `pry` gem to the development part of the project, bundle it, then insert the code `require 'pry; binding.pry'` to various part of the code to controller and view to make sure where the set `@instagram` variable has become.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, sorry I'm still very new to RoR. Do you mind explaining how do I make sure where the set `@instagram` variable has become? I have added the gem, bundled it and inserted the code `require 'pry; binding.pry'` to the start of my controller and view files.

Comment: @AlfredLua  here is the set of the variable `@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")`

Comment: @AlfredLua you just have to observe valud of `@instagram` in controller before and after the set, and in a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from my friend, I realised where I went wrong and how to correct the NoMethodError.

There's 2 parts to this answer: 
1) Adding the Instagram code into the pins controllers 
2) Using a separate controller for Instagram data

Note that this answer is specifically for the One Month Rails tutorial and may or may not be applicable directly to every web application.

**1) Adding the Instagram code into the pins controllers**

- Mattan Griffel was right about the `respond_with(@pins)` part.
  `respond_with(@pins)` caused my controller action to skip the rest of
  the part. So when I changed the order of the code, it worked.
- I most likely made another mistake when I tried to remove it after Mattan suggested it so it didn't work then (see comments above).

Part of my pins_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    respond_with(@pins)
  end
```

**2) Using a separate controller for Instagram data**

- I got the same NoMethodError even when I used a separate controller because while I declared `@instagram` in my instagram_controller.rb, I was trying to render the data into my pins view (views/pins/index.html.erb). However, I did not declare `@instagram` in my pins_controller.rb.
- So I copied `@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")` from instagram_controller.rb and pasted it into my pins_controller.rb under the index method; like this:

Part of my pins_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")
    @pins = Pin.all.order("created_at DESC").paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    respond_with(@pins)
  end
```

Similarly, `respond_with(@pins)` causes my controller action to skip the rest of the part, so `@instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("264208635")` has to be added before `respond_with(@pins)` and not after. Then, it worked.